# Подсветка курсора по клику

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, курсор

Всем привет, у меня есть вот такая вот кнопка:

```
 <div class="recordPanel">
        <span>Записать</span>
    </div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку курсор становился, как на картинке(только без замены курсора картинкой), а при клике на другую картинку возвращался обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    $(".recordPanel").click(function()
    {
      $(".recordPanel").toggleClass("recording");
    });

    function isRecording()
    {
      return $(".recordPanel").hasClass("recording");
    }
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        if (isRecording())
        {
          $(".mouse-circle").css("display", "block");
          $(".mouse-circle").css("left", event.pageX - 30/2+5);
          $(".mouse-circle").css("top", event.pageY - 30/2+5);
        }
        else
        {
          $(".mouse-circle").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
.mouse-circle
{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,145,255, 0.3);
  background: rgb(0,145,255);
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="mouse-circle"><i class="fa fa-cursor"></i></div>
 
 <div class="recordPanel">
        <span>Записать</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: То что я и хотел,но возможно ли это показать без jquery? На чистом js?) Буду очень благодарен) Чистый js более понимаю

Comment: Хороший вариант. Только события нажатия срабатывать не будут)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko почему же?

Comment: @Demon__ANTпотому что под мышкой находится `div.mouse-circle`. И все события нажатия срабатывают на него. Попробуйте "отжать" кнопку *Записать*.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko достаточно для `.mouse-circle` добавить свойство `pointer-events:none`. Тогда не будут учитываться клики в этот блок.

Comment: @AntonMironov спасибо, я в курсе, что надо сделать) Но в ответе этого нет.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а где именно это надо указать,можете сказать по подробнее)

Comment: @Desperado надо добавить в класс `.mouse-circle` стиль `pointer-events:none`

Comment: Исправил в примере